# CSS :not on items which do not contain any id

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following markup and I know that I can apply style on `li` which do not contain specific id as the example shows, but how do I simplify the example below to be like if not id than apply another style?

```css
ul > li:not(#_1):not(#_3)
```

```html
<ul>
<li id="_1"></li>
<li></li> 
<li id="_3"></li>
<li></li>
<li id="_5"></li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the negation along with the attribute selector.

The selector `li:not([id])` would select only `li` elements which doesn't have an `id` attribute.

```css
ul > li:not([id]) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="_1"></li> <!-- will not be selected -->
  <li></li>         <!-- will be selected -->
  <li id="_3"></li> <!-- will not be selected -->
  <li></li>         <!-- will be selected -->
  <li id="_5"></li> <!-- will not be selected -->
  <li id=""></li>   <!-- will not be selected -->
</ul>
```